# How can I multiply the elements of a list using loops?

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

{1,1,1,-2,1,2} 
How acn I multiply the elements in the list using loops?

Comment: The simplest loop would be `Fold[Times, {1, 1, 1, -2, 1, 2}]`

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a loop here, I would go with:

```
Times @@ {1, 1, 1, -2, 1, 2}
```

But if you really need a procedural approach use a [`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) loop instead (even if it's probably not a good idea).

Comment: Obligatory comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951)

Answer (score 2):

```
t = 1; Do[t *= elem, {elem, {1, 1, 1, -2, 1, 2}}]
t
{* -4 *)
```